# Using linq date formats ? using asp.net?

Tags: linq-to-sql

In web application [asp.net], i am using  Linq, in linq how can i display only time format.
I am getting total date, can i get only time format from the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `String.Format("{0:t}", dt);`. it will display short time strings. for more options have a look at [this](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)